# Creating a temporary copy of the sheet before emailing

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible in excel to do the following:

```
1. User clicks 'SEND SHEET'
2. Script is ran on a temporary sheet, modifying it's content
3. Temporary sheet is attached to the email
4. The original sheet does not change
```

The email part is not an issue, however I don't know how to perform step 2 in one self contained excel file.

Please ask questions if my issue is unclear

Comment: How is the content modified? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of copying a single worksheet to a new workbook, making a change in the copy, saving the copy, and closing the copy. *(original not changed)*

```
Sub MakeACopy()
    ActiveSheet.Copy
    '
    '   We are now in a new workbook
    '
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value = "stuff"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="Temporary.xlsm", _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    '
    '   We are now back in the original workbook
    '
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```